# Cabbage, Eggplant, and Cauliflower with white-ish dry spots

Tags: seedlings, eggplant, cabbage, cauliflower, deficiency

I've got eggplant, cabbage and cauliflower seedlings growing inside in peat moss with some all-around fertilizer (24-8-6). However, the edges of their leaves are drying and curling up, and some of them have dry, beige spots in the middle. I thought it might have been a calcium deficiency, so I boiled some eggshells and added them to each of them. I've attached an image of the cabbage seedlings. It's been 2 days now, and their condition is deteriorating. First of all, is this indeed a calcium deficiency? And if so, what should I do to rapidly restore the leaves?

[image: cabbage 1]

[image: cabbage 2]

[image: cabbage 3]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, they are over fertilized. Especially if you add 24-8-6. Diluted 1-2-1 should suffice for those growing roots.

Comment: I actually ended up adding more fertilizer, and they seem like they're doing better now. I'll need to wait for a few more weeks to see if they fully bounce back or not.